# why datagridview not showing private property of binded class type

Tags: c#, .net, class, datagridview, private-members

I have a Datagridview `dgvDTMUDetails` which show a list of class `BlclsStaffMember`

```
public void ShowData()
{
     BlclsStaffMember OBlclsStaffMember = new BlclsStaffMember();
     List<BlclsStaffMember> liStaffMember = new List<BlclsStaffMember>();
     liStaffMember = OBlclsStaffMember.getAllStaffMember();
     dgvDTMUDetails.DataSource = liStaffMember;
}
```

where the defination of class is:

```
public class BlclsStaffMember 
    {
        private int Perno { get; set; }
        private string Surname { get; set; }
        private string Forename { get; set; }
        private string Name { get; set; }
        public  List<BlclsStaffMember> getAllStaffMember()
        {
            DTMUEntities ODTMUEntities = new DTMUEntities();
            return ODTMUEntities.STAFF_MEMBER.Select(s => new
                    {
                        s.Perno,
                        s.Surname,
                        s.Forename
                    }).ToList().Distinct().Select(s1 => new BlclsStaffMember
                    {
                        Perno = s1.Perno,
                        Forename = s1.Forename,
                        Surname = s1.Surname,
                        Name = s1.Surname + ", " + s1.Forename + " [" + s1.Perno + "]"
                    }).ToList().Distinct().ToList();
        }
}
```

**The problem is:** *the datagridview is not showing any data when the property of class is marked as private*

while when properties are public then datagridview is showing data
why?

also in case when i use listBox in place of Datagridview it also populating data even when properties are private.

could someone please explain

Comment: Private member can not be accessed by another class. Can you show code how `ListBox` was succesfully bounded to the private members of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid auto-generates the columns, depending on the properties of the class it's bound to, unless you define the columns manually.

I'd suggest you make your properties public and have private fields to manipulate the data.
An example:

```
private string _surname;
public string Surname 
{ 
     get
     {
          return _surname;
     }
     set
     {
          _surname = value;
     } 
}
```